# Create CIImage from CVImageBufferRef

Tags: ios

I am trying to create a `CIImage` object from `CVPixelBuffer`, everything went well up to step 3.

But in step 4:

```
[[CIImage alloc] initWithCVPixelBuffer:imageBuffer options:(__bridge_transfer NSDictionary *)attachments]
```

returns nil.
So please give me solution for my problem....Thanks in advance.

```
CMSampleBufferRef sampleBufferRef = [readerVideoTrackOutput copyNextSampleBuffer];

CVImageBufferRef imageBuffer = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sampleBuffer);

CFDictionaryRef attachments = CMCopyDictionaryOfAttachments(kCFAllocatorDefault,        
                            sampleBuffer, kCMAttachmentMode_ShouldPropagate);
CIImage *image = [[CIImage alloc] initWithCVPixelBuffer:imageBuffer options:(__bridge_transfer NSDictionary *)attachments];
```

Comment: Are you running this on the simulator?